# writing dataframe into influxdb

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb

I tried official documents and found it was only okay for following generated dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(30)),
                  index=pd.date_range(start='2014-11-16',
                                      periods=30, freq='H'))
```

However, sometimes my dataframes will have "dtype" in the end of each column, which is the possible reason for not writing dataframe successfully.

Now I found the dataframe which can be inserted into the db also has a dtype when I call its values. However, somehow I made a df and call dataframeclient successfully but no data loaded.

Could somebody who is experience give me some more examples about writing python timeseries dataframes into influxdb? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post raw data and code that demonstrates how you get `dtype` at the end of the column as this is unclear

Comment: @EdChum I think he's referring to the ``tuple`` type of each row when invoking ``df.iterrows()``. It returns, for example, ``(Timestamp('2014-11-16 00:00:00', offset='H'), 0    0 Name: 2014-11-16 00:00:00, dtype: int64)``.

Comment: array([['14:59:50', 2.98, '-0.01', 10, 2980],
       ['14:59:45', 2.99, '0.01', 50, 14950],
       ['14:59:40', 2.98, '-0.01', 19, 5662],
       ['14:59:35', 2.99, '--', 220, 65780],
       ['14:58:50', 2.99, '--', 19, 5681],
       ['14:58:30', 2.99, '--', 82, 24518],
       ['14:58:25', 2.99, '--', 20, 5980],
       ['14:58:15', 2.99, '-0.01', 308, 92092],
       ['14:58:00', 3.0, '0.01', 48, 14400],
       ['14:57:55', 2.99, '-0.01', 18, 5382]], dtype=object)

Comment: @EdChum like previous comment